# ¿Dónde esta el error?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente funcion que elimina un elemento de un array segun su indice.

```
function removeFrmArray(arreglo,item) {
    var i = arreglo.indexOf(item);

    if ( i !== -1 ) {
        arreglo.splice( i, 1 );
    }
}


removeFrmArray('usuarios',nick);
```

Pero no me funciona, siempre me devuelve -1, segun lo que veo en la consola.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: 'usuarios' no es un array, es una cadena, prueba a pasar un array y definir nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el único error que tenia tu código era tener los argumentos invertidos, de cierta forma, porque le pasabas el **arreglo** como `String`, y el **elemento a eliminar** como `variable`, te dejo una corrección:

```
<script>
//Definimos el arreglo
Usuarios = ["Nick", "Joel", "Gustav", "Michael"];
//Imprimimos el arreglo completo
console.log(Usuarios);
//Creamos la funcion que recibe como parametros primero el item a eliminar, y luego el arreglo
function removeFrmArray(item, arreglo) {
    var i = arreglo.indexOf(item);
    //Si el item existe, lo removemos, de lo contrario imprimimos un mensaje de que no se elimino nada
    ( i !== -1 ) ? arreglo.splice( i, 1 ): console.log("Nada que eliminar");
}

//Llamamos a la funcion pasandole como primer parametro el elemento a eliminar, y despues el arreglo
removeFrmArray('Nick',Usuarios);
//Vemos el resultado
console.log(Usuarios);
</script>
```

Déjame saber si te funcionó.

Comment: Perfecto si me funcionó, aunq ya había definido mi array solo que olvide colocarlo en la pregunta xD. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegra saber que se solucionó tu problema. Un saludo.